# systemLayoutSizeFitting not returning correct height for view which has a table view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I need to dynamically set a container height. This is in the event of using a container view with view controllers which may change.

```
let frame = viewController.view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
containerHeight.constant = frame.height
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

I am using the above code for getting the required height of the new view controller so that I can set the container views height.

This seems to work fine on any view which doesn't contain a scroll view. If the view has a scroll view so for example I have a view with a title, tableview and button at the bottom of the tableview. The height calculated doesn't account for the tableview.

Is there anything special I need to do when calculating the height of a view which has a scroll view

Comment: You can get scrollView view height with `scrollView.contentSize.height`, use it to calculate your containerView height

Comment: The issue is im wanting to calculate the size of the view controller so update the container view height

Comment: @JackWilkinson - are you trying to have your table view grow (get taller / shorter) based on its content? If not, are you sure your constraints are set correctly?

Comment: Im trying to find out the size of a view based on all its constraints. When this view is used in a navigation controller its all fine... im trying to use it within a container view which itself is embedded in a scroll view, and as a result I need to update the container view's height constraint. This is why im trying to find the height of the view controller providing all its contstraints are set

Comment: @JackWilkinson - when using it in a navigation controller, the constraints are added for you - that is, the table view's height is constrained by the view. When trying to load it into a container view, **you** have to set constraints to control the height of the table view.